# Clicking on the system monitor button does not work anymore from one day to the next (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: software-installation, gui, software-uninstall, system-monitor

My taskbar on the left side displays the system monitor symbol. By just clicking on it, I was able to open it. But suddenly, it stopped working. I clicked on it and Ubuntu seemed to load and open the process but quitted doing so after a while – and acted as if I have never clicked on that button. Yesterday, everything was still fine. Today, Ubuntu is acting that weird.

Answer (score 1):

It does this sometimes if you keep your system running for days without restart.

to solve this whenever it happens:

Run in the terminal

```
killall gnome-system-mo
```

then

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

it should work fine after this.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome-system-monitor is not installed as part of Gnome on Ubuntu, but instead, for some vague reason Ubuntu installs it as a snap app. This is why your apt commands did not work.

To install gnome-system-monitor as part of gnome, you must first uninstall the snap version:`snap remove gnome-system-monitor`

after that you can install native gnome-system-monitor with apt: `sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor`

Comment: so why exactly is this necessary? it unexpectedly quit and when i try to restart it wants me to install it as a snap, even though "Ubuntu Software" thinks it is already installed!

Comment: It is not necessary per se. There seemed to be a bit of confusion as to how it was installed. So if you want system monitor to be an integral part of the gnome experience, the snap method will not work. It probably quit because the snap was updated in the background. This will not happen if you remove the snap version and install the apt version.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  that might explain why the appearance of the icon for the app changed around the same time.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have tried to install the system monitor all over again by typing `sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor` into my terminal. This did not work. I tried to uninstall it with `sudo apt purge gnome-system-monitor` and install it again with `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor`. It still did not work. So, I just typed in `gnome-system-monitor` and it worked. But it was displayed as a **separate** instance on my taskbar. So, I just deleted the old link and made myself a new one. Now, everything is fine again.